# How can I replace the variable which is in test.js file from gruntfile?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

For example I have this code, with this one I can replace only string in any files, but I need something like that due to replace the value of variable.

```
'string-replace': {

  dist:{
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      src: 'test.js'

    }],
    options: {  
      replacements: [{
        pattern: 'blabla',
        replacement: 'blabla1'

      }],     
     }
  }
```

Comment: "I need something like that but for variables" => What are you trying to do with this? Rename variables...?

Comment: no,I need replace the value of the variable

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do? It would help with why you can't just do that as a parameter to your function that you would be unable to configure after Grunt is done with your code.

Comment: I have the codes which one is already was written with someone ,and now I want to change something inside of the codes.Like I have gruntfile and inside of the gruntfile I should write the code which one will get access to the varaible and replace it the variable is in the another file.My question how can I get the access to this variable.Is it possible upload the file here then I can explain better

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. You can replace variable assignments like below so they get your new value. Is this what you are looking to do?

```
'string-replace': {

  dist:{
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      src: 'test.js'

    }],
    options: {  
      replacements: [{
        pattern: 'var myVar = oldValue', //replace var assignment
        replacement: 'var myVar = newValue'//var has newValue now

      }],     
     }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
You can only access the current value of myVar during runtime. You cannot use grunt to determine that. You can however set myVar to be whatever value you want as above. Or for example if you had code like:

```
if(myVar)
{
  //do this block
}
```

You could do text replace to insert

```
var tmp = myVar
myVar = true;
if(myVar){
//will now always run
}
myVar=tmp // resetState
```

Comment: thanks for answer.Yes you are right,but the problem like let's say we don't know the value of the myVar,we know only the name of variable and it is myVar then how can we do it in the same way like you wrote?

Comment: Can we do like I will make this variable global then I can take the value easily